# Return json result for a filestream

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-web-api, filestream

I am trying to implement downloading a file. I have a web api action method that returns a FileStreamResult.

```
response.Content = new StreamContent(this.FileStream.StreamInstance);
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                {
                    FileName = FileStream.Name
                };
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
```

This is consumed by a service using a REST API Client. This client expects a JSON and de-serializes using,

```
SafeJsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(_responseContent, this.Client.DeserializationSettings)
```

where,

```
_responseContent = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I get the following error since the api response is not proper json, `Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: %. Path '', line 0, position 0`. How do I return a filestream as json from web api?

Thanks

Comment: you would have to have a JSON object where the file data is a property of the JSON object. If you have a C# object where one property is an array of bytes (containing the file content) and you return that as your response then Web API will serialise the bytes (to base64 I think) to form part of the JSON

Comment: Thanks that did it!